# How to update multiple different figures with different data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I think it might be silly to ask this question but I could not find any matching solution to my problem on google. Hope someone can help.

Simply put, I want to plot different functions on the same plot same figure, not subplots,since most online solutions i found use subplot to do this. My purpose is for better comparison that different data lines are on the same figure same plot, but with different color and different legend.I have 2 figures because the second figure is just something else with the same idea.

I tried with the following code. But the subplot got overwritten everytime of the loop. I don't want the old line erased. I want every loop to update figure 1 and figure 2 separately without erasing the previous data lines.

```
    fig1 = plt.figure(1)
    fig2 = plt.figure(2)
    for diffSteps,listpair in fixed_table_plots.items():
        ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        ax1.scatter(listpair[0],listpair[1],s=2000,label="error_step_"+str(diffTableSteps))
        ax1.legend()
        plt.show()

        ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        accuracy_bw = [x - math.log(y,2) for x,y in zip(listpair[0],listpair[1])]
        ax2.scatter(listpair[0],accuracy_bw,s=200,label="accuracy bw_step_"+str(diffTableSteps))
        ax2.set_xlabel("input int bw")
        ax2.set_ylabel("total bw accuracy")
        ax2.legend()
        plt.show()
```

Really appreciate any help!

Update:

```
    for diffSteps,listpair in fixed_table_plots.items():
        plt.figure(1)
        ax1.scatter(listpair[0],listpair[1],s=2000,label="error_step_"+str(diffTableSteps))
        ax1.legend()

        plt.figure(2)
        accuracy_bw = [x - math.log(y,2) for x,y in zip(listpair[0],listpair[1])]
        ax2.scatter(listpair[0],accuracy_bw,s=200,label="accuracy bw_step_"+str(diffTableSteps))
        ax2.set_xlabel("input int bw")
        ax2.set_ylabel("total bw accuracy")
```

This worked well for me only thing is that the plt.show() can not be called in the middle. Is there a way to dynamically show the plots ? Also feels weird to reactivate plots. Please let me know if this is a good way...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is similar to [How to keep the previous plot and not clear the figure after calling plt.show() without simply repeating the call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460691/how-to-keep-the-previous-plot-and-not-clear-the-figure-after-calling-plt-show/60460869) However, that linked post is about updating a single figure and you're asking about **multiple** figures. I think you will be able to adapt the following minimal example to your code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)

fig1 = plt.figure()
fig2 = plt.figure()
plt.close(fig1)
plt.close(fig2)

for i in range(3):

    plt.figure()
    fm = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    fm.canvas.figure = fig1
    fig1.canvas = fm.canvas
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x) + i)

    plt.figure()
    fm = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    fm.canvas.figure = fig2
    fig2.canvas = fm.canvas
    plt.plot(x, np.cos(x) + i)

    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```